# Trouble with UTF-8 Encoding; what I stored and What I see in user interface

Tags: java

I am getting trouble with utf8 encoding. It's correctly stored in the database but not getting exact same on UI. Like ÇÈÆ saved in the database and I am getting  ÃÃÃ on UI. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like while picking data from db, somewhere you are not setting UTF8 encoding properly. What database are you using?

Comment: I am using mysql.

Comment: Make sure your char and varchar columns use the `utf8mb4` charset (not utf8!), and use `character_set_server` in your JDBC URL, not characterEncoding.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-charsets.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are dealing with non-ASCII characters in MySQL database, it is safer to use utf8mb4 instead of utf8. MySQL utf8 is not true utf8 as it only uses maximum 3 bytes for storing Unicode characters which is not right because there are Unicode characters that even take four bytes like emoji characters and may be others.

Once your chosen encoding at MySQL is correct, you may still run into issues because of following reasons,

1. You need to ensure your jdbc connection string is correct and sets
   this parameter in it, useUnicode=true
2. While you are returning the response that contains unicode characters, make sure you are setting response encoding correctly, something like this,

   httpServletResponse.setContentType("text/json; charset=UTF-8");

If you don't do this, you response will show unexpected characters.

3. After you read the response on client side, make sure you use UTF8 encoding instead of your default encoding which could be platform specific like CP1252 etc.

If you did any thing wrong in above three points, you will not see expected unicode characters. Sometimes it is really frustrating when we do everything right and just make one mistake in any of the above points.